# How to add a texture area to an abnormal shape

Tags: texturing, materials

I import a model, which was made in 3ds Max. The model is missing a colored section. How can I "draw in" or recreate the white shape shown in the image?

[image: comparison]

Comment: Is it an armature?

Comment: Can you show the topology? Maybe it's material got deleted and need to be assigned again?